# Проверка на инициализацию плагина jPages

Tags: jquery

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста как осуществить проверку на инициализацию плагина jPages.
Необходимо чтобы в мобильной версии он вызывался, а при планшетной, десктопной, если раннее был вызван - разрушался. Если не был вызван - вызывается. Заранее большое спасибо!

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function() {
    var windowWidth = screen.width;
    if(windowWidth < 768){
        $("div.catalog_holder").jPages({
            containerID : "itemContainer",
            fallback    : 500,
            perPage : 1,
            midRange : 4
        });
    }else if(...){
        $("div.catalog_holder").jPages("destroy");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не работал с этим плагином, но твою функцию сделал бы так:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  JPages();
});

JPages();

function JPages() {
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $("div.catalog_holder").jPages({
      containerID: "itemContainer",
      fallback: 500,
      perPage: 1,
      midRange: 4
    });
  } else {
    $("div.catalog_holder").jPages("destroy");
  }
}
```

Она будет срабатывать и при загрузке и при ресайзе. + есть функция [.unbind()](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/), которой ты можешь отменить иниц. функции.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное за помощь!!) Вы меня очень выручили)